# App stops on button click with error message "Appname has stopped unfortunately"

Tags: android

## Header 1

This is the code that i have used. i want to add a name to a database. when i enter the name into the EditText, it accepts and when i click the submit button, it shows the message "App_name has stopped unfortunately"
    activity_main.xml

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:text="USERNAME"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="SUBMIT" />

</RelativeLayout>`
```

## Header 1

Main_Activity.java

```
package com.example.dbconcept;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button b;
String user;
EditText usr;
SQLiteDatabase db;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        try{
            db=openOrCreateDatabase("Mydb",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
            db.execSQL("create table table1(user varchar(50))");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        user=usr.getText().toString();
        db.execSQL("insert into table1 values('"+user+"')");


    }



}
```

Comment: You are not initializing your Edit text in onCreate()?

Comment: Here is the logcat for this app...

Comment: Try the answer from BlackBelt below, it will address your issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have not intialized `usr`

just add

```
usr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1)
```

to your `onCreate`

Comment: @bb that's what i am talk in about

Answer (score 2):

You forget to intialized the usr `EditText`.

```
usr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1)
```

Add this in `onCreate(...)` after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`